# Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support

Tags: javascript, html, flash, silverlight, plupload

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<title>Plupload - Custom example</title>

<!-- production -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>

<!-- debug
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/moxie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/plupload.dev.js"></script>
-->

</head>
<body style="font: 13px Verdana; background: #eee; color: #333">

<div id="uploader">
    <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize the widget when the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    // Setup html5 version
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        url : "/examples/upload",

        chunk_size : '1mb',
        rename : true,
        dragdrop: true,

        filters : {
            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size : '10mb',
            // Specify what files to browse for
            mime_types: [
                {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
                {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
            ]
        },

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize: {
            width : 200,
            height : 200,
            quality : 90,
            crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
        },

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap'
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey guys I keep getting error

> Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.

The code I am using is up there, I don't know how to fix that I tried all the runtimes on this Plupload.
I've been trying for many days to fix this issue but found no help.

Comment: Look at your console. `$` is not defined. You need to load jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[JQuery - $ is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to load jQuery (and based on the docs for plupload, you also need jQuery UI)

Comment: I recently got this error after upgrading to a newer version of plupload. I fixed by finding the file jquery.ui.plupload.js in the plupload folder and adding a link to that folder in my pages which used plupload

Answer (score 0):

I put the code below and it worked for me:

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.extend({
    live: function (event, callback) {
       if (this.selector) {
            jQuery(document).on(event, this.selector, callback);
        }
        return this;
    }
});
</script>
```